# subsetting panel data that has the complete time dimension

Tags: r, data.table, panel

I have a panel data and as you might notice some of the individuals have missing observations in certain times. For instance "C" is missing data point for 2001 and "D" for 2002 and 2003.

```
> mydata
    id year sales profit
 1:  A 2000  2000    200
 2:  A 2001  2050    245
 3:  A 2002  2100    290
 4:  A 2003  2150    335
 5:  B 2000  2200    380
 6:  B 2001  2250    425
 7:  B 2002  2300    470
 8:  B 2003  2350    515
 9:  C 2000  2400    560
10:  C 2002  2500    650
11:  C 2003  2550    695
12:  D 2000  2600    740
13:  D 2001  2650    785
```

I tried something like below

```
subset(mydata, year==c(2000:2003)
```

the result is as presented below.

```
   id year sales profit
1:  A 2000  2000    200
2:  A 2001  2050    245
3:  A 2002  2100    290
4:  A 2003  2150    335
5:  B 2000  2200    380
6:  B 2001  2250    425
7:  B 2002  2300    470
8:  B 2003  2350    515
9:  C 2000  2400    560
Warning message:
In year == c(2000:2003) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

What I need is the data that includes entities with full period, starting from beginning, 2000, to the end, 2003. In this case it would be like this.

```
   id year sales profit
1:  A 2000  2000    200
2:  A 2001  2050    245
3:  A 2002  2100    290
4:  A 2003  2150    335
5:  B 2000  2200    380
6:  B 2001  2250    425
7:  B 2002  2300    470
8:  B 2003  2350    515
```

Thank you for your time and answer in advance, but I would really appreciate if the answer is a little simpler as I am highly unexperinced and has just begun to learn about R.

Comment: Maybe a better way to do this, but something like `mydata[, ind := all(2000:2003 %in% year), id][(ind)]`?

Comment: Because I want only the member of "id" column that has full length, i.e., starting from 2000, 2001, 2002, and ending in 2003 so I have tried below code         subset(mydata, year %in% c(2000:2003))

Comment: Thank you very much friend, it was exactly what I needed!

Comment: OK. Added the suggestion as an answer....

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
library(data.table)
mydata[, ind := all(2000:2003 %in% year), id][(ind)]
#    id year sales profit  ind
# 1:  A 2000  2000    200 TRUE
# 2:  A 2001  2050    245 TRUE
# 3:  A 2002  2100    290 TRUE
# 4:  A 2003  2150    335 TRUE
# 5:  B 2000  2200    380 TRUE
# 6:  B 2001  2250    425 TRUE
# 7:  B 2002  2300    470 TRUE
# 8:  B 2003  2350    515 TRUE
```

---

With "tidyverse":

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(all(2000:2003 %in% year))
```

Sample data (which is how you should share it in the future):

```
mydata <- structure(list(id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "C", "C", "C", "D", "D"), year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
    2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2000L, 2002L, 2003L, 2000L, 2001L
    ), sales = c(2000L, 2050L, 2100L, 2150L, 2200L, 2250L, 2300L, 
    2350L, 2400L, 2500L, 2550L, 2600L, 2650L), profit = c(200L, 245L, 
    290L, 335L, 380L, 425L, 470L, 515L, 560L, 650L, 695L, 740L, 785L
    )), .Names = c("id", "year", "sales", "profit"), row.names = c(NA, 
    13L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R's `ave` to count id groups and keep only records equal to year length of 4:

**data**

```
txt = '    id year sales profit
A 2000  2000    200
A 2001  2050    245
A 2002  2100    290
A 2003  2150    335
B 2000  2200    380
B 2001  2250    425
B 2002  2300    470
B 2003  2350    515
C 2000  2400    560
C 2002  2500    650
C 2003  2550    695
D 2000  2600    740
D 2001  2650    785'

df <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE)
```

**code**

```
df$grp_cnt <- ave(df$year, df$id, FUN=length)

df <- transform(subset(df, df$grp_cnt == 4), grp_cnt = NULL)

df    
#   id year sales profit
# 1  A 2000  2000    200
# 2  A 2001  2050    245
# 3  A 2002  2100    290
# 4  A 2003  2150    335
# 5  B 2000  2200    380
# 6  B 2001  2250    425
# 7  B 2002  2300    470
# 8  B 2003  2350    515
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution using a *join*:

```
mydata[mydata[, uniqueN(year), by = id][V1 == 4L, .(id)], on = "id"]
```

> ```
>    id year sales profit
> 1:  A 2000  2000    200
> 2:  A 2001  2050    245
> 3:  A 2002  2100    290
> 4:  A 2003  2150    335
> 5:  B 2000  2200    380
> 6:  B 2001  2250    425
> 7:  B 2002  2300    470
> 8:  B 2003  2350    515
> ```